# .map array by its objects keys then .map each key for values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reduce, array.prototype.map

if I have an array of objects like:

```
[{"name":"chair","type":"metal"},{"name":"chair","type":"wood"},{"name":"table","type":"plastic"},...]
```

how can I map it so it returns:

```
<h3>chair</h3>
metal
wood

<h3>table</h3>
plastic

ecc.
```

what I tried is:

```
return (
   <>
    {Object.values(myarray.reduce( (c, e) => {
        if (!c[e.name]) c[e.name] = e;
        return c;
    }, {})).map((title, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            {myarray.filter(one => one.name === title)
            .map((item, i) => (
                <div key={i}>{item.type}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    ))}
</>
)
```

but it throws

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {name, type}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
> array instead.

Comment: Why are you returning everything as an object?! So, why is your return statement wrapped in { }. And it seems like in <h3> you should use title.name and in your div title.type. And actually you should also rename the input parameter from title to object or something

Comment: First of all you return the object entry in your reduce methods. That is what throws the error. You need to return an Html element or string into your array

Comment: @marks I omitted irrelevant divs above and below it. I added empty enclosures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce data array to an object, then use the object to render.

```
 // reducer

   let data = [
    { name: "chair", type: "metal" },
    { name: "chair", type: "wood" },
    { name: "table", type: "plastic" }
  ];

  let data2 = data.reduce((xuu, val) => {
    xuu[val.name] = xuu[val.name] || [];

    xuu[val.name].push(val.type);

    return xuu;
  }, {});

 // render

  {Object.keys(data2).map((key, index1) => {
    return (
      <div key={index1}>
        <h3>{key}</h3>
        {data2[key].map((val, index2) => {
          return <div key={index2}>{val}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  })}
```

You can play around with [my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-sea-ieq8s?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks it works. What isn't clear to me is why do I have to use return inside the .map process while .mapping an array doesn't need it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple logic with grouping

```js
var data= [{"name":"chair","type":"metal"},{"name":"chair","type":"wood"},{"name":"table","type":"plastic"}]

var groupBy = (xs, f) => {
        return xs.reduce((r, v, i, a, k = f(v)) => ((r[k] || (r[k] = [])).push(v), r), {});
    };

var groupData = groupBy(data, (d) => d.name);
$.each(groupData,function(key,val){ 
  $('#pnlData').append("<h3>"+key+"</h3>")
  $.each(val,function(skey,sval){
  $('#pnlData').append("<span>"+sval.type+"</span> <br/>")
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pnlData"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code

```
const a = [{"name":"chair","type":"metal"},{"name":"chair","type":"wood"},{"name":"table","type":"plastic"}];

const b = {};
a.map(row => {
    b[row.name] = b[row.name] || []
    b[row.name].push(row.type) 
})

console.log(b) // you can check results here...

// result: {"chair":["metal","wood"],"table":["plastic"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is the function you need:

```js
const things = [{name: 'chair', type: 'metal'}, ...]

things.reduce((a, _) => {
    a[_.name] = a[_.name] || [] // make array for this thing
    a[_.name].indexOf(_.type) < 0 && a[_.name].push(_.type) // add type if not already present
    return a
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` function to grouping all entries by name. Then you can use `Object.keys` or `Object.values` to get entry name or types.

```js
array.reduce((reducer, current) => {
    if (!reducer[current.name]) {
        reducer[current.name] = [];
    }

    reducer[current.name].push(current.type);
    return reducer;
}, {})

// result : { chair: ["wood", "metal"], table: ["plastic"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible to change the data structure/array objects. I think it would be easier if it looks something like this. Your new Array:

```
const myArray = [
    {
      "name":"chair",
      "types":["metal", "wood"]
    },
    {
      "name":"table",
      "types":["plastic"]
    }
  ]

  //in your ui code would be 
  myArray.map(item => {
    return <div>
        <h3>item.name</h3>
        {item.types.map(type => <div>{type}</div>)}
    </div>
  })
```